# How to enable c++11 in Kdevelop

Tags: c++, kdevelop

I have switched from Eclipse and Code::Blocks and would like to know how to set a project in Kdevelop to c++11 mode (std=c++11)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer because the comment got too big.

KDevelop uses external build systems for its projects, so you can always find and edit make/cmake/*whatever*make to add `-std=c++11` to the compile commands. It doesn't have anything internally or options to set it, at least for CMake based stuff AFAIK. I had to add `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++1y")` to `CMakeLists.txt`, however I am not sure if this satisfies you.

Perhaps as you have indicated, the best practice is to append the command to the current flags at some point of `CMakeLists.txt`: `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")`.

Alternatively, you can do essentially the same from the KDevelop menus. When you go *Project* -> *Open Configuration*, in the left panel you should have CMake and Make.

For CMake you can click *Show Advanced*, then check Show Advanced Values, then a listing of cached values for the project configuration shows up. You can find `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` there and add `-std=c++1y` to there.

I don't work enough with make utilities to know if this can be done with the options given there.

I also don't think there is anything smarter in KDevelop that would allow it to be more portable e.g. between different compilers.

The option:

[image: Option]

The dialog:

[image: Dialog]

Comment: I have kdevelop 4.6 but there is no open configuration submenu in Project.

Comment: As a side note for anyone reading, there's this alternative : 
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

Comment: I have `4.6.60` and I have this option. I added the pictures. And of course, how you set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to add this option is up to you. I showed how to set the flags, you append the `-std=c++11`. Maybe I should have made it more detailed, but it was just an example. I included this suggestion.

Comment: Oh yes right , there is open configuration but it looks disabled i ignore why

Comment: You have to have a project chosen in the Projects panel. By default this panel is located left of the code. There are also 4 tabs or so, Filesystem, Projects, Classes, and Documents. It's hidden beneath the menu on the screen shot.

Comment: If i could upvote you eveb more would have done. I hope future users will benefit from this well documented issue.

Comment: I dont have CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, what do i do?